# can I add Python classes together?

Tags: python, metaclass

I want to combine two (or more) Python classes together in a way that may not work with subclassing. I start with

```
class Foo:
    def process(self):
        print(self.fields)
        print(self.items)

class AFoo(Foo):
    fields = ['a', 'A']
    items = ['dog', 'cat']

class BFoo(Foo):
    fields = ['b', 'B', 'Bee']
    items = ['badger', 'potato']
```

and I want to define combined classes such as `ABFoo` where `fields` and `items` are the sum  of fields and items in the base classes.
I think I may be able to write something like this, but it's unwieldy:

```
class ABFoo(AFoo, Bfoo):
    fields = [f for cls in ABFoo.__bases__ for f in cls.fields]
    items  = [f for cls in ABFoo.__bases__ for f in cls.items]
```

I think this might be an application for a metaclass, but I still don't really understand them. Note that I want to define a combined **class** not add two **objects** of these classes together.

Comment: "Note that I want to define a combined class not add two objects of these classes together." Okay, but **why**?

Comment: @Karl Because `__init__` behaviour will change based on the contents of `fields` and `items`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with metaclasses it is possible to implement this behavior.
You can even choose to either customize the inheritance behavior, so that the merging of specific sequence fields is done when creating a subclass, or actually implement the `+` operator to work with classes, so you could literally "add classes together". It may not be the most intuitive behavior for people reading your code, though.

So, let's first check how this can be done through ordinary inheritance and multiple inheritance.

So, when creating a new class, even if it inherits from several parents, the `__new__` and `__init__` methods of the metaclass are called. But better yet, since Python 3.6, the `__init_subclass__` method is called in the parent classes, so there is not even need for a metaclass. Here, I add some custom logic so that along your hierarchy you can specify which fields to merge as you inherit classes:

```
class Foo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, merge_fields=()):
        all_fields = getattr(cls, "_fields_to_merge", set()).copy()
        all_fields.update(merge_fields)
        cls._fields_to_merge = all_fields

        new_fields = {}
        for attribute in all_fields:
            items = set()
            for ancestor in cls.__mro__:
                if attribute in ancestor.__dict__:
                    items.update(ancestor.__dict__[attribute])
            setattr(cls, attribute, list(items))

        super().__init_subclass__()

    def process(self):
        print(self.fields)
        print(self.items)

class AFoo(Foo, merge_fields=("fields", "items")):
    fields = ['a', 'A']
    items = ['dog', 'cat']

class BFoo(Foo):
    fields = ['b', 'B', 'Bee']
    items = ['badger', 'potato']

class ABFoo(AFoo, BFoo):
    pass

ABFoo().process()
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a', 'Bee', 'B', 'A']
['dog', 'cat', 'badger', 'potato']
```

For being able to "add" classes with the "+" operator, one would just need to write the logic in the `__init_subclass__` above in an `__add__` method of a metaclas, that would need to be used in a baseclass - it would work the same, but the behavior would be restricted to classes created with the "+" operator - inherited classes would behave as normal

Comment: I posted the first two paragraphs with the ideas only, before doing the example code, and marked it would be continued with "[WIP]". During those minutes someone passed by and did not like this - all well, part of the game. But the code is good and the text is correct, and with a non-negative score more people may be able to use it.